# Changing a specific Active Directory attribute programmatically

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm working on a tool to automate some Active Directory tasks such as removing users from groups, changing user's passwords, and updating attributes for the user such as their telephone number, etc. I'm leveraging both `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

I'm having trouble finding a way to modify the **Deny this user permissions to log on to Remote Destop Session Host server** option (see picture below).

[image: Attribute I would like to edit]

Does anyone know how to change this option?

I've looked all over the internet and can't seem to find anything except a PowerShell script that references the **msTSAllowLogon** attribute, but when I look at the attribute in AD's attribute editor for a user that has that option checked and one that doesn't, **msTSAllowLogon** is `<not set>` for either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer but decided not to pursue it. For anyone needing help with this same issue, this option is contained in the `userParameters` blob. For a lot of information about this and a possible way to implement this, see the following links:

http://webactivedirectory.com/active-directory/active-directory-attributes-for-remote-desktop-services/

http://daduke.org/linux/userparameters.html